# Visio VBA Get Pasted Shapes

Tags: vba, visio

I have a macro which works differently between Visio 2003 and 2010.  I'm copying and pasting a shape onto the page, and trying to get a pointer to the pasted shape.  In 2003, that shape is just the last shape on the page (`set ShpObj = PagObj.Shapes(PagObj.Shapes.Count)`).  In 2010, however, it seems the pasted shape isn't always set to the last shape on the page.

Currently I am logging all the unique shapes on the page before the paste operation, then identifying new shapes after the paste operation.

I tried monitoring the application ShapeAdded event, but it doesn't seem to fire for paste operations.

Are there any other ways I might pick up the pasted shape(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you doing your copying?  Visio 2010 gained some more enumerations giving greater control over the paste operation in terms or position and container and callout behaviour which might effect collection order:

[Visio 2010 Page.Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766937%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Visio 2007 Page.Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427155%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

It's a shame Paste doesn't return a selection, but have you looked at Shape.Duplicate and Selection.Duplicate which return shape and selection objects respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of Visio's layer functionality by creating a new temporary layer before the paste operation and set the Active cell for the layer to true. Setting Active to true means that any new shapes added to the page will be added to this layer. Then when the paste operation is finished you can get all of the shapes on this layer.  To clean up you can delete the temporary layer without deleting the shapes.

Answer (score 0):

In Visio 2010, the newly pasted shape (or shapes) are always selected when you paste them. So After a paste operation, ActiveWindow.Selection or similar will get you the newly-pasted shape.